# Performing SELECT but INSERT when NOT EXISTS in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table created using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `name_to_id` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);
```

And a common query this table would like to answer is `name` to `id` look-up, but if the `<name, id>` pair does not exist in the DB, then also insert a new entry and return the newly inserted `id`.

Can I know should I do that in MySQL?

Comment: In a single query? No. But you could create a procedure.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a common pattern

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Strawberry, this cannot be performed in a single query.

However, here is a stored procedure that should do what you expect. First, it uses the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE` syntax to insert new names ; this actually relies on the `UNIQUE` key that you correctly set up on the `name` column.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_id_by_name(IN  p_name VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO name_to_id(name) VALUE(p_name) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = p_name;
    SELECT id FROM name_to_id WHERE name = p_name;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sUuuQPaNmC4oxVw9vQTXve/2)**.

---

This approach is efficient, but the downside of `ON DUPLICATE KEYS` is that it wastes `id` sequences : everytime the query is called, the sequence is autoincremented (even if a record already exists). This can be seen in the fiddle.

Here is another approach, that won't burn sequence numbers :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_id_by_name(IN  p_name VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    DECLARE p_id bigint(20) unsigned;
    SELECT id INTO p_id FROM name_to_id WHERE name = p_name;
    IF (p_id IS NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO name_to_id(name) VALUE(p_name);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE 
        SELECT p_id;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sUuuQPaNmC4oxVw9vQTXve/3)**.

Comment: I think OP wants a function, not a procedure. Otherwise I definitely agree with your second version.

Comment: @Nick : could be too... Hard to tell, as the OP seems currently unresponsive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I personally preferred the 2nd solution.  As for the first solution, is it guaranteed to be able to read your own write?

Comment: @keelar : what do you mean by *read your own write*? PS: I provided fiddles for both solutions, you can play around and see how the procedures behave.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this on stored proc, if the select statement did not return a result, then you can execute the insert statement

Comment: You should tell him about `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID of the newly inserted record.